# How to assign values of one list to values of second list when their length is not equal?

Tags: python

Input is:

```
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
A = ['A','B','C']
```

Output should be:

```
C = {'A':[1,4,7], 'B':[2,5], 'C':[3,6]}
```

The length of lists are dynamic (not fixed) but length of list B is always going to be greater than length of list A.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a dictionary comprehension and slicing:

```
{j: B[i::len(A)] for i, j in enumerate(A)}
```

Output:

```
{'A': [1, 4, 7], 'B': [2, 5], 'C': [3, 6]}
```